# Reload UIViewController without going back to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, reloaddata

I am developing a science game for the iPad that lets you choose a level and some questions about science elements are displayed and the user must choose the correct answer. I use a `UITableview` to display the "level select" screen and once the user selects the level the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` sets an int currentLevel on the "game screen".

After the level is completed I want to create an `UIButton` so that the user can go to the next level without going back to the "level Select" screen (`UITableView`). 
Essentially I want to reload the view and set the int currentLevel to display the correct level for the game

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alloc your level selector view controller and present it modally in current view.

```
UIViewController *levelPicker = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:levelPicker animated:YES];
[levelPicker release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't want to show the level select view again, I just want a button to go to the next level

Comment: You use a different UIViewController for each level?

Comment: That isn't efficient because that means I must have 10 separate UIViewControllers each with the same code. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: No, I was just asking, it wasn't a suggestion :D. My suggestion is to create a new view controller and present it when you press the next level button. And you pass to your new view controller the next level number in your init method.

Comment: I think you need method wich will reload full view according to currentLevel var. When button pressed make currentLevel++ and reloadView...